# How do I create a no-javascript url hash handler for my website?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ok, I'm not sure how this is normally done. But I've got a script that basically empties a div of content and then loads content from a div from a separate webpage, without reloading the current page. This works great.

It's taken from this example actually, from net tuts (great site btw)

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/011_jQuerySite/sample/index.html

And the guy who wrote this even though about handling the url's since the url don't change when using his method. So he wrote a javascript snippet that looks up the url and loads the content accoringly. Which is not working btw.

But I was thinking about people who don't have javascript enabled, or iPhone and iPad users ;)
Copying URLs and sending to a friend won't work at all.
So how is this typically done? And can it be done without javascript? Possibly by php?

I'm using this code basically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

`// Check for hash value in URL
var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }
});`

$('.dynload').live('click', function(){
 var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
 $('#content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
 $('#ajaxloader').fadeIn('normal');
 window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length);

function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
 }
 function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').fadeIn('fast',hideLoader());
 }
 function hideLoader() {
    $('#ajaxloader').fadeOut('normal');
 }
 return false;

});

Comment: iPhone and iPad users do have Javascript enabled.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking java.. Silly me, it's not even the same thing at all. :p Thanx for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

See [Tabtastic](http://phrogz.net/js/Tabtastic/index.html)

In a nutshell, link to the id of the element you want to go to, and don't hide the content if JS isn't available.

Comment: I don't hide the content if JS isn't available. Each link just works like the old fashioned way. It's just the linking and URL handling I'm having trouble with. So basically, you're saying I should link to the element I want to go to? Is there an easier way of doing that without having to load several scripts? Don't think I quite understand how this is done. I'll edit my first post to include some code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the hash-part of the URL through PHP. You can only access that from the browser.

However, you could just change the code to using a normal GET query string instead. So put whatever you put behind the # symbol, behind ?hash= in the URL instead and work with it that way.

Comment: Hmm, so I've read some about these rewrite engines. Is this what I'm basically looking for?